# Migrating from slf4j to log4j 2 in gradle

Tags: log4j, gradle

In my current project we are using log4j as logger, but as per enhancement we have to migrate to log4j 2. we are using gradle as project dependency tool. so anyone can please tell me is there any way to bridge the slf4j-log4j 2 in build.gradle file like we are doing in maven

Comment: You need to add the same dependency(s) as you would in Maven.

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle change this line

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7' //or similar one
```

with does two:

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.0-beta9" 
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0-beta9"
```

it worked for me.

Remember that format and name of log4 configure file has changed